# BigQuery SQL syntax error FOR function ("Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword FOR at [7:18]")

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I needed to concatenate data in one column (cont_url) based on dev_id. I was able to successfully do this in MS-SQL with this query, but I need to do this in BigQuery.

```
select
    dev_id,
    stuff(
    (SELECT '|||' + cont_url
      FROM `test_table_sample`
        WHERE  dev_id = a.dev_id
         FOR XML PATH (''))                --Error is here
        , 1, 1, '') as testlist
from
    `test_table_sample` as a
group by
    dev_id
```

When I have the table mounted in Big Query and try to run the same query, I get a syntax error.

**Expected ")" but got keyword FOR at [7:18]**

I do not know what I am doing wrong and how is BigQuery standard SQL syntax different than T-SQL.

I have included a sample table of data.

```
test_table_sample
dev_id  cont_url
Device1 Link1
Device1 Link2
Device1 Link3
Device1 Link4
Device2 anotherLink1
Device2 anotherLink2
Device2 anotherLink3
Device2 anotherLink4
Device2 anotherLink5
```

Here are the results of the query.

```
Results 
dev_id  cont_url
Device1 Link1|||Link2|||Link3|||Link4
Device2 anotherLink1|||anotherLink2|||anotherLink3|||anotherLink4|||anotherLink5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery allows you to just aggregate strings.  The syntax is much simpler:

```
select dev_id, string_agg(cont_url, '|||') as testlist
from `test_table_sample` as a
group by dev_id;
```

That said, I strong advise you to use arrays instead:

```
select dev_id, array_agg(cont_url) as testlist
from `test_table_sample` as a
group by dev_id;
```

Much better than awkwardly delimited strings.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the answer. I guess there is no way to have the url data in one cell ( I will be counting the unique user paths and wanted all of the links together in one cell for each user)

Comment: @Putnik . . . `string_agg()` does what you explicitly are doing in SQL Server.  `array_agg()` is preferable probably.

Comment: Do both if you are curious!  They are using the same aggregation.